# how to click on "not now" in instagram notification using selenium and python

Tags: python, html, selenium, bots, web-deployment

I am trying to login to Instagram with an "instagram bot" that I am currently coding. I have gotten it past the login screen but i have problem with the following pop up) says
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMA6h.png

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"


class instabot:

def __init__(self,username,pw):
#def __init__(self):
    self.driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
    self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")``

    sleep(2)
    #to give input to username
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input').send_keys(username)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input').send_keys(pw)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]').click()
    

    sleep(1500)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following wait for the element to be clickable and then click.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you I just directed the page to my profile and the pop up didappeared

Answer (score 0):

After your login you have to find the "Not now" button and then click it. I'm not sure how familiar you are with the browser dev tools and the DOM. You have to look for an `id`, `class` or you could use the `xpath` like you did with your login.

There are many ways to find and identify this button. When you found it, call the `.click()` function.